# No products in my categories

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I am having a problem with my categories I have delete all products in the categories but it shows me that it y to 10 products in the categories so that it has nothing

Comment: sorry. didn't get  your question !

Comment: Clear you cache and perform reindexing then check

Comment: http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/646773Capturedcran20150626025926.png Why it shows me 20 products in my category while I have no products

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR I try but nothing changes

Comment: Delete var/cache folder and refresh cache in admin panel.

Comment: try but nothing changes

Comment: are you talking about the number 20 in (20) after your Category name,.? this doesnt show the number of products in the category. Also this category has no products. so isnt this correct.?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the method used to delete the products, rebuilding the "Category Products" index should fix the counts. 
    **Go to System > Index Management. Check the box next to "Category Products", change the action (top right) to "Reindex" and click submit.** –

please Log into admin which will still be working and under configure select manage shops and click on your shop name. Your root category will be empty, simply select the correct root category.

Comment: The selected category is good
but I still have the same problem

Comment: i have suggeted:-System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Shop > Items per Page    I have only the german version here at the moment :-/ And I'm not sure whether this is an extension.

And you can have a look into Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar there is the limit set.

Comment: Look capture screen : http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/522865Capturedcran20150626142632.png

Comment: is demo  product on theme

Comment: No I have not install the theme database

Comment: Go to System > Index Management. Check the box next to "Category Products", change the action (top right) to "Reindex" and click submit. –

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25227/discussion-between-ashvin-monpara-and-webevolution).

Comment: please use this code:-SSH users can use the following command to flush Magento caches:

1)$ find ./var/cache -type f -delete

2)FTP users can use the following command to cleanup Magento caches:

    mrm -r ./var/cache ; mkdir ./var/cache